Provide App clients for Amplify and Alb Listener
So I have an issue. I have existing cognito user pool and one client without client secret. And I need to make auth operation through amplify. So I used amplify import auth and chose the user pool. Actually the issue here is that I need this client to access alb listener and I need the value of client secret for alb listener. Is it possible to create two clients and how to achieve and implement this?
Thanks in advance.
I have tried to create two clients but I am  not sure whether it will be executed correctly or not? how these clients will communicate with each other how amplify will know about it?

This is so fringe, no-one knows what you are talking about. If you want to get a response, you have to be more descriptive in your ask. Nonetheless, I hope you got your issue resolved using trial and error. Nobody on the web is going to be able to help you, I'm afraid.
